# button click event doesnt work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to switch the views, but when I'm in the second view, the back event click doesnt work.. I don't know what's wrong.

Pls, see my code and help me!

[Part1](http://pastebin.com/kV52cbWh)

[Part2](http://pastebin.com/Ke1iWz01)

```
public class t extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
   Button volta;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.janela2);

      volta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
      volta.setOnClickListener(this);

   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      if (v == volta) {
         startActivity(new Intent(t.this, MainActivity.class));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Claudio, Please do not use paste bin, and post relevant parts of the code in the body of your question.

Comment: Sorry, I have posted all the code because I don't know what can be wrong...And the code have only the button functions...All is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override onBackPressed. Change your MainActivity as below

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private boolean goBack = false;           


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                Button sobre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
                  sobre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                           goBack = true;
                           setContentView(R.layout.janela2);
                   }
                   });


        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
        //If you have switched to R.layout.janela2 then go back
        if (goBack){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            goBack = false;
            return;
            }
        //else do default action
        super.onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

Comment: can you post the code in your question. It is not shown in pastebin.

Comment: You haven't override onBackPressed in the MainActivity. Read the above posted code carefully

Comment: the code still does not work doing it, already downloaded with Antico a project with another version of android sdk worked, will be that the problem is this new sdk? I tried on my mac and it did not work tbm creating a new project, as you have me post the source code? a new project that works?

Answer (score 1):

If you want two layouts then use viewflipper. If you want two activities (java classes) AND two layouts separately then use:

```
Intent i = new Intent (this, myClass.class);
startActivity(i);
```

To start the Activity and NOT setcontentview

So here:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                       startActivity(new Intent (MainActivity.this, t.class));
                                         OR IN THE CASE OF T.CLASS:
                       startActivity(new Intent (t.this, MainActivity.class));
               }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following code, I hope it might help you

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Button sobre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            sobre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {

               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, t.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
    }
 }
```

### In t.java

```
public class t extends Activity{

    Button volta;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.janela2);
    }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();
 }
}
```

Comment: This is what `onBackPressed()` [already does.](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29)

Comment: Why do you call `finish()` in `onStop()` now? The Activity is either finishing already or you are defeating the purpose of `onRestart()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override  `onBackPressed()` method if you want to back button functionality in your application. i.e.

```
public void onBackPressed() {

     Intent start = new Intent(CurrentClass.this,Next_Activity.class);
      startActivity(start);
     finishActivity(0);
 }
```

Comment: What? I did not understand you

Comment: I elaborate answer let me know still any query.